# Sending the User model's password to the client side in Sailsjs App

Tags: node.js, sails.js

While learning Sailsjs I am going through an [example Chat application code](https://github.com/ichabodcole/Sails.js_ChatApp_v0.9.3). But it seems after successful login or signup the functions in MainController to do these are sending the entire User object found in db or created in db to the client side by the res.send(user) line.

Am I correct here? Is it not wrong and insecure to send password?

Or It is just not sent? If so, how?

```
login action from the api/controllers/MainController.js:

    login: function (req, res) {
        var username = req.param('username');
        var password = req.param('password');

        // Users.findByUsername(username)...
        // In v0.9.0 the find method returns an empty array when no results are found
        // when only one result is needed use findOne.
        Users.findOneByUsername(username)
        .done(function loginfindUser(err, usr){
          if (err) {
            // We set an error header here,
            // which we access in the views an display in the alert call.
            res.set('error', 'DB Error');
            // The error object sent below is converted to JSON
            res.send(500, { error: "DB Error" });
          } else {
            if (usr) {
              var hasher = require("password-hash");
              if (hasher.verify(password, usr.password)) {
                req.session.user = usr;
                res.send(usr);
              } else {
                // Set the error header
                res.set('error', 'Wrong Password');
                res.send(400, { error: "Wrong Password" });
              }
            } else {
              res.set('error', 'User not Found');
              res.send(404, { error: "User not Found"});
            }
          }
        });
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `toJSON` function in your Users model's attributes that removes the password

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        ...

        toJSON: function() {
            user = this.toObject()
            delete user.password
            return user
        }
    }
}
```

if you're properly encrypting your user's passwords, sending them down to the client isn't *horrible*, but it is still regarded as a bad practice.